# How to create a timed input in python with a correct answer?

Tags: python

How would I create a program which asks the user for an input but if they dont respond with an answer within 5 seconds tells them that the time is up. But if the user gets the question right within the 5 seconds tells them that its right?

This is the code I have tried:

```
user_answer = None
def check():
if user_answer == 10:
  print("Good")
  return
time.sleep(5)
if user_answer != None:
    return
print("Too Slow")

Thread(target = check).start()

user_answer = int(input("5+5 = "))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using this: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+time+limit+for+input code to make a timer on the input but I'm not sure how to make it so that if you input a particular answer it will print out something else.

Comment: Try to post the code that you have tried. As far as I understand, a question without a code, even with errors, is not welcome.

Comment: OK, I posted the code!

Answer (score 0):

You check bring the check into in the same thread as `int(input("5+5 = "))` and leave the `check()` for checking timeout only. If the user entered input or timeout, you can use [os_exit(status_code)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit) to terminate the entire application

```
import os
import time
from threading import Thread

timeout = 3
user_answer = None
def check_timeout():
    time.sleep(timeout)
    if user_answer != None:
        return
    print("\nToo Slow")
    os._exit(0)

thread = Thread(target = check_timeout)
thread.start()

def check_anwser():
    if user_answer == 10:
      print("Good")
      return
    if user_answer != None:
      print("Wrong")
      return
user_answer = int(input("5+5 = "))
check_anwser()
os._exit(0)
```